# Showing angles are preserved by isometry.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Im trying to show that a rigid transformation (isometry) preserves angles. Here is my approach so far. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a rigid motion transformation defined by $f(p) = \textbf{A}p + b$ where $\textbf{A}$ is a linear, orthogonal matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$ I figured I'd show that the angles are preserved by using the cosine formula and proving that $$\frac{f(x) \cdot f(y)}{\|f(x)\|\|f(y)\|} = \frac{x \cdot y}{\|x\|\|y\|}$$ but I can't seem to make the algebraic journey from the left to the right (I know somewhere I'm likely to use the fact that $A^TA = I$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angle between the vectors is nothing but the angle between the lines represented by the vector x and y respectively. Now f preserves angle means that the angle between the lines spanned by f(0),f(x) and f(0) and f(y). Now we calculate

$ \frac{<f(x) - f(0), f(y) - f(0)>}{\|f(x) - f(0)\| \| f(y) - f(0)\|}  = \frac{<Ax,Ay>}{\|Ax\|\|Ay\|} = \frac{<x,y>}{\|x\|\|y\|}$

the last step folows from the fact that A is an orthogoanl linear transformation. The definition i wrote for angle preserving maps has generalization to infinitesimal form. For example all conformal maps are angle preserving and in that case angle between lines and the angle between the images of these lines donot make much sense.